# ValueError: View function did not return a response not caught by Exception exception handler

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

I added an exception handler method to my Flask app to catch all the unexpected errors which occur during request processing so I can control which response is returned to the client.

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_default(error):
    utils.log('Unexpected error happened: ' + str(error))
    ...
```

However it seems if there is a programmatic error when processing request (not returning response) the respective exception

```
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

is subsequently not handled by this default handler as I expected.

Why is this so ? 
What can be done about this?

Answer (score 1):

All Flask routes need either a implicit response

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask("the_flask_module")

@app.route("/")
def home_page():
    return "I'm An Implicit Response!"

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

or an explicit response

```
from flask import Flask, make_response
app = Flask("the_flask_module")

@app.route("/")
def home_page():
    response = make_response("I'm an explicit Response!")
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = "Malarkey"
    response.headers['Nonsense'] = "Seattle Never Has Traffic"
    return response

app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

This includes error handlers

```
@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_default(error):
    utils.log('Unexpected error happened: ' + str(error))
    ...
    return "A string or response object."
```